# Running two animations side-by-side using ImageMagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I have two animations (.gif files) I want to run side-by-side. Can this be done with ImageMagick?

Moreover, I want to start one of the gifs after thirty frames of the other have passed. Can this be done as well? Otherwise, I can manually insert thirty frames of blackness into one image, but it would be easier to automate this step with ImageMagick, because I will potentially be doing this many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script does the job :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# $1 : first gif
# $2 : second gif

mkdir first
cd first
convert $1 x%04d.gif
cd ..
mkdir second
cd second
convert $2 x%04d.gif
cd ..

for filename in first/*
do
  filename=`basename $filename`
  montage -tile 2x1 -geometry 512x512 first/$filename second/$filename concat$filename
done
convert concat* output.gif

rm -rf first
rm -rf second
rm concat*
```

Comment: the montage command is what did it eventually, but I resolved this on my own months ago...

Answer (score -1):

`convert` if provided with more than 1 input image and provided with the `-delay` option will output animated gif's if the output format is gif.

I used to use this link as my reference guide back in the day: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/

Comment: This does not do what I want. Instead, it concatenates the animations. I want it to run the two simultaneously side by side.